# Donwload file in AngularJS from API REST generate file corrupted

Tags: angularjs, rest, download, report

I've generated a excel report on the API REST and send it to the front (AngularJS). If I hit the url directly from the browser everything is working fine, but no if I do it from Angularjs, the is dowloaded but when I try to open it say :

> Excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format or
> file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
> corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

This is my code :

```
$http.get(urls.SERVICE_API + "informe/"+ angular.toJson(informeDTO)).then(
                            function(response) {
                                console.log(response.data);
                                console.log(response.headers('Content-Type'));

                                console.log(response.config);

                                var headers = response.headers;
                                 
                                var filename = "IOPReport.xlsx";
                                var contentType = response.headers('Content-Type');
                         
                                var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
                                try {
                                    var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: contentType });
                                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                         
                                    linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
                                    linkElement.setAttribute("download", filename);
                         
                                    var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                                        "view": window,
                                        "bubbles": true,
                                        "cancelable": false
                                    });
                                    linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
                                } catch (ex) {
                                    console.log(ex);
                                }
                                console.log("GenerarInformeIOP - success");
                                deferred.resolve(response);
                            }, function(errResponse) {

                                console.log("GenerarInformeIOP - error");
                                deferred.reject(errResponse);

                            });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }

            } ]);
```

Any idea why is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H I resolved it adding the response type to the GET

```
    var config = { responseType: 'blob' };
                        $http.get(urls.SERVICE_API + "informe/"+ angular.toJson(informeDTO), config).then(
.....
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also need to adding BOM if it is CSV:

```
// HTTP response data
var data = response.data;
if (type === 'csv') {//Adding BOM at start of content if it is a csv
    data = '\uFEFF' + data;
}
```

You need to append the linkElement to body before clicking:

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
linkElement.setAttribute('download', filename);
linkElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.body.appendChild(link);
linkElement.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did but still same problem

Comment: What's your contentType, It should be some string like 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'